# Code for Yoshi's Island DS mini games?

Tags: yoshis-island-ds

In the original Yoshi's Island for Super Nintendo, you could enter a code (hold select, then press x,x,y,b,a) to get to a screen that would allow you to replay the various mini games.

Is there something like this in Yoshi's Island DS?

Comment: In the GBA version, the code is **L-L-B-A-R** while holding select -- possibly this works for the DS version too? Although I doubt it, mostly because the DS's button layout would make this a PITA to enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code in the DS version to unlock all minigames.

However, [minigames unlocked](http://www.mariowiki.com/Yoshi%27s_Island_DS#Minigames) by collecting [character coins](http://www.mariowiki.com/Character_Coin) are accessible from the main menu.